# Why does ? extends ... accept child for return value but not as a variable type in main?

Tags: java, generics, collections

the following code

```
public static ArrayList<? extends Animal> readAnimals(){
    return new ArrayList<AnimalChild>();
}
```

doesn't give compilation errors but when I do the following

```
ArrayList<AnimalChild> = readAnimals();
```

Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<capture#1-of ? extends Animal> to ArrayList.

It wants me to do type conversion and then gives me unchecked cast warning. Why is that?

Comment: Every `ArrayList<AnimalChild>` must be a `ArrayList<? extends Animal>`, but not every `ArrayList<? extends Animal>` is a `ArrayList<AnimalChild>`.

Comment: Hm, how do you think I should make it work as intended? Because when I try to add <T extends Animal> in the method itself it then wants me to do a conversion on a return type, that's even more confusing because I'm returning a T extends Animal type, in this case AnimalChild

Comment: How do you intend it to work?

Comment: I want the method to return different types of arraylist, all of which extends Animal, based on some conditions and then assign them in main

Comment: So you should do `ArrayList<? extends Animal> = readAnimals();` in `main`, because you have no idea what specific kind of animal it is going to return there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used for this example:

```
class Animal {  }
class AnimalChild extends Animal {  }
```

With those classes defined above, the following compiles fine:

```
public static ArrayList<? extends Animal> readAnimals() {
    return new ArrayList<AnimalChild>();
}
```

However, as you found, this does not compile (compiler error added, too):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<AnimalChild> x = readAnimals();
}

java: incompatible types: java.util.ArrayList<capture#1 of ? extends Animal> cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<AnimalChild>
```

Why? Since the return type of the *method* is `ArrayList<? extends Animal>` (not `ArrayList<AnimalChild>`), the compiler is telling you it cannot make sense of the return types, one of them cannot be converted to the other.

Why doesn't the compiler understand that the return value is `ArrayList<AnimalChild>`? Because it's using the *declared* return type in the method signature, not the runtime type of the actual return value. The *caller* to the method will also see the return type as declared by the method signature.

Here's a really simple example of the same behvior:

- static method declared with return type of java.lang.Object
- implementation returns a java.lang.String
- caller tries to receive the result as a String

```
static Object getString() {
    return "";
}

String string = getString(); // error: does not compile
```

A similar error arises as with your example:

```
java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

To fix your code, you should change this:

```
ArrayList<AnimalChild> animals = readAnimals();
```

To something like this where the declared type of "animals" matches the declared return type of the method:

```
ArrayList<? extends Animal> animals = readAnimals();
```